# Rails 4 - Controller test error, Active Record association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I will post all files below the question. I am very new to testing. I'm trying to write a controller test for my app. The model is Ownerships. Ownerships is owned by Team. I'm using the paperclip gem to attach a logo to each team.

When I run the test, I get the follow error:

```
 1) Error:
 OwnershipsControllerTest#test_Should_retrieve_results:
 ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `logo_file_name' for  nil:NilClass
 app/views/ownerships/round1.html.erb:23:in `block in _app_views_ownerships_round__html_erb___2932533286089946925_70246915278440'
app/views/ownerships/round1.html.erb:18:in `each'
app/views/ownerships/round1.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_ownerships_round__html_erb___2932533286089946925_70246915278440'
test/controllers/ownership_controller_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:OwnershipsControllerTest>'
```

It's complaining about how I'm dealing with a missing logo in the view. This is the portion of the round1.html.erb it doesn't like:

```
    <% if ownership.team.logo_file_name == nil %>
    <td></td>
    <% else %>  
        <td><%= image_tag ownership.team.logo.url(:medium) %></td>
    <% end %>
```

The problem is not the paperclip attachment itself. ANY reference to the Team model throws an error. If I remove the code related to the logo, the following also generates the same error:

<%= ownership.team.name %>

Whats really perplexing is the my test for the index method doesn't throw an error. The code for the index and round1 views are the same! How can I setup my test so that the attributes from the associated models are recognized?

ownership_controller_test.rb

```
 require 'test_helper'

 class OwnershipsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 test "Should retrieve index" do
 get :index
 assert_response :success
 end

 test "Should retrieve results" do
 get :round1
 assert_response :success
 end
 end
```

ownerships.yml

```
 one:
 round: 1
 pick: 1
 team_id: 1
 player_id: 1

 two:
 round: 1
 pick: 1
 team_id: 1
 player_id: 1
```

teams.yml

```
 one:
 name: Browns
 division: East
 logo_file_name: logo.jpg 

 two:
 name: Chargers
 division: West
 logo_file_name: logo.jpg
```

Models

```
 class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :player
 belongs_to :team

 validates :round, :pick, :team_id, presence: true
 end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ownerships
has_many :players, through: :ownerships 

validates :name, presence: true
validates :division, presence: true

has_attached_file :logo , :styles => { :small => '10>', :medium => '40>', :large => '60>' }
validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

The relevant parts of ownerships_controller.rb

```
class OwnershipsController < ApplicationController

def index
@ownerships = Ownership.all.select { |t| t.player_id == nil}
Rails.application.config.counter = (256 - Ownership.all.select{ |t| t.player_id == nil}.count)
end

def round1
@ownerships = Ownership.all.select { |m| m.round == 1}
end

private
def ownership_params
params.require(:ownership).permit(:round,:pick,:team_id,:player_id)
end
```

Comment: This is because the `Ownership` has no `Team` that's what the error is saying. It says I don't know how to call `logo_file_name` on `nil` because `ownership.team #=> nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add references to team in your ownership fixture.  You can reference by label.

```
one:
  round: 1
  pick: 1
  team: one
  player_id: 1
```

Or, your current approach would also work, just add the primary key to the team

Ownership

```
one:
  round: 1
  pick: 1
  team_id: 1
  player_id: 1
```

Team

```
one:
  id: 1
  name: Browns
  division: East
  logo_file_name: logo.jpg
```

See also: [More info about relations in fixtures](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Label+references+for+associations+-28belongs_to-2C+has_one-2C+has_many-29)

Comment: Thanks Swards. I eventually figured it out. I had read the documentation, but their example was not the best.